# Tastypie, non-orm endpoints

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm trying to figure out if it makes sense to create non-orm endpoints for my api. I've seen the "Using Tastypie With Non-ORM Data Sources" section of the Docs, but I'm thinking more about processing forms and such. For example: Passing data to an end point that would process and send email. Im not gonna save anything to the db, I just want to validate the form and send it. Am I missing something in the docs or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just define a function in your `views.py` and handle the request without it really using tastypie:

Here's an example for registering a new user to to a Django webapp; you can probably repurpose it to send an e-mail instead by processing the form data from the request.

```
# In views.py:
...
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http import Http404
from django.utils import timezone
from models import *
from api import *
from django.utils import simplejson
...

# REST endpoint for user registration
# Enforces server-side mediation (input validation)
# On failure, raises Http404
# On success, redirects to registration success page
def register_user(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')

    # acquire params
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    repeatpw = request.POST['repeatpw']
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']

    # Server-side mediation to check for invalid input
    if username == '' or username is None:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Invalid Username')

    if len(username) > 30:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: username must be 30 characters or fewer')

    if len(first_name) > 30:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: first name must be 30 characters or fewer')

    if len(last_name) > 30:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: last name msut be 30 characters or fewer')

    if len(password) < 4:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Password too short')

    if password != repeatpw:
        raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Password Mismatch')

    # This try-except block checks existence of username conflict
    try:
        test_user_exists = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
        if test_user_exists != None:
            raise Http404('Server-side mediation: Username exists')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    # Input passes all tests, proceed with user creation
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, 'default@nomail.com', password)
    group = Group.objects.get(name='Standard')
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    user.groups.add(group)
    user.is_staff = False    
    user.save()

    # Build confirmation JSON
    confirmation = {
            'action': 'register_user',
            'username': username,
            'success': 'yes',
    }

    json_return = simplejson.dumps(confirmation)

    # return JSON of the success confirmation
    return HttpResponse(json_return, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Yeah I considered that. However I like the idea of using the Authentication/Authorization mechanisms in Tastypie. So using a view will be plan b :D